# Are people in this community interested in having a new site for other Geospatial technologies?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Regarding [this discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11581/remote-sensing-in-geoscience) that took place about 1 year ago and considering all the comments, I want to have a similar discussion here since CV is a community somehow related to remote sensing because concepts like **classification**, **pattern recognition**, **PCA**, **fuzzy theory**, **ICA**, **change detection** have a lot of applications in RS.  I suspect there are some geodesists, photogrammetrists, remote sensing experts who attend in this community to solve their problem and I want them participate in this discussion.  I think that there are concepts in remote sensing that cannot be covered just in Cross Validated + GIS and I have given some reasons [here](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4019/19874), [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21707/142064) and [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21610/142064).

**So are you interested in having a new site?**

**If yes, What do you want the proposal of the site be named?**

**Will I have the support of some members of this community if I make a proposal for a new site or change the name of the current proposal?**

**If yes, which percent you think will commit in the new site?**

I just beg you that participate in the discussion. Even a small comment will be considered. I'm really confused about the name of the proposal and have some doubts about whether we really need a new site or not?

(Note that [a similar question](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4021) was asked in GIS.)

Also, a chat room has been created: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27633/remote-sensing-experts-room

Answer (score 5):

The GIS SE site welcomes Remote Sensing questions [since a long time ago](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4018/should-gis-se-be-widened-to-be-geomatics-se/4022#4022), and it has been explicitly made official in past years. The [help center page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> Geographic Information Systems is a question and answer site for people interested in GIS, **Remote Sensing**, Photogrammetry, Geodesy and Surveying, as well as Programming/Databases specific to the aforementioned. It is built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites.

You mentioned in your question:

> I think that there are concepts in remote sensing that cannot be covered just in Cross Validated + GIS and I have given some reasons here, here and here.

But I agree with [Devdatta Tengshe's comment](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4018/should-gis-se-be-widened-to-be-geomatics-se/4019#comment7039_4019) that all examples provided in your first link have on topic issues in GIS SE. Some of that questions would require a more focused approach or have their title rewritten, though. For example:

Examples of too broad questions which would need more focus:

> 1- What is the most accurate algorithm to apply with use of hyperspectral data to predict soil organic matter>carbon prediction and soil moisture?
>
> 10- How can I calibrate (or correct) my LiDAR intensity images and/or intensity values of point cloud? What should be process steps for that?

Examples in which the title would need to be rewritten so to avoid answers like: "Yes, I do", "No, we can't", and so on:

> 3- Do you know what type of surface indicates Bowen Ratio=0.34?
>
> 6- Can we draw the spectral curve for a single pixel from a satellite image (for each band)?

In CV SE we have at least one related tag to RS which is [spatial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spatial) (x 475). As long as the RS questions relates to our [on topic list](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) they can be asked here too.

---

> So are you interested in having a new site?

Sorry, I am not. It is already hard to keep CV SE and GIS SE organized and making them a useful repository, that more splitting of content would only bring more work to less people, without necessarily adding more quality to existing repositories.

On the other hand, if something is not working the way it should in one of the existing SE sites, I'd rather concentrate efforts trying to improve what is not working.

Comment: @Have a look at [this](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/4027/19874), [this](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/4023/19874) and [this](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/4018/19874). Yes, it was your suggestion on August 2015 to widen the scope but also you or other elite members of GIS.SE didn't reject the creation of [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry) and [2016 ad](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/4147/19874) gained 16 upvotes and [2017 ad](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/4466/19874) has gained 7 upvotes so far

Comment: When I tried to close the proposal ones, there were [some disapprovals](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/22491/142064). So I don't know you can decide about the proposal yourself. I don't think it will get enough 100 committers to reach the beta anyway. I have decided o contribute more and answer unanswered RS questions in GIS.SE if the proposal fails at last. But I can't help about photogrammetry. Any way although it's a niche but seems that there are some people in this community interested in having such site. Because we had some experienced followers that are already members of

Comment: GIS.SE members, 36 committers with at least 200+ reputation in one of the other sites and 16, 7 votes during years 2016 and 2017